# Combining multiple lines of output to a single line using BeautifulSoup findAll with multiple classes/tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm trying to build a scraper that collects text from a web page.  I'm looking at two specific divs with different class names ("product-image" and "product-details").  I'm looping through them, grabbing the text from each "a" and "dd" tag within the div.

It's worth noting that this is the first Python program I've ever written...

Here's my code:

```
list_of_rows = []
for row in soup.findAll(True, {"class":["product-image", "product-details"]}):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll(['a', 'dd']):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
```

When I print out list_of_rows, I'm getting the following output for each pass in the loop:

> [price]
>
> [title],[author],[publisher],[blah],[blah],[blah]

The [price] is coming from the "product-image" div block.
The [title],etc. is coming from the "product-details" div block.

So basically, findAll and the loop I've written output different lines for each div block I'm looping through.  The result I want to get is a single line of output for both blocks, like this:

> [price],[title],[author],[publisher],[blah],[blah],[blah]

Is there a way to do this within the current flow I have, or do I need to break this out into multiple loops, pull the data separately, and then combine?  I've gone through all the Q&A on StackOverflow and other sites, and while I can find instances of findAll loops with multiple classes, I can't find any examples of how to reduce the output to a single line.

Here's a snippet from the web page that I'm parsing.  This snippet appears 1-x times in the html I'm parsing, where x is the number of products on the page:

```
<div class="product-image">
    <a class="thumb" href="/Store/Details/life-on-the-screen/_/R-9780684833484B"><img src="http://images.bookdepot.com/covers/large/isbn978068/9780684833484-l.jpg" alt="" class="cover" />
        <div class="price "><span>$</span>2.25
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="product-details">
    <dl>
        <dt><div class="nowrap"><span><a href="/Store/Details/life-on-the-screen/_/R-9780684833484B" title="Life On The Screen">Life On The Screen</a></span></div></dt>
        <dd class="type"><div class="nowrap"><span><a href="/Store/Browse/turkle-sherry/_/N-4294697489/Ne-4">Turkle, Sherry</a></span></div></dd>
        <dd class="type"><div class="nowrap"><a href="/Store/Browse/simon-and-schuster/_/N-4294151338/Ne-5">Simon and Schuster</a></div></dd>
        <dd class="type">(Paperback)</dd>
        <dd class="type">Computers &amp; Internet</dd>
        <dd class="type">ISBN: 9780684833484</dd>
        <dd>List $15.00 - Qty: 9</dd>
           </dl>
</div>
```

Any pointers or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From you question , I came up with 2 results .. I am not sure what you are looking for ... So I'm posting both the cases

**First case - extend the list instead of appending it**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """<div class="product-image">
    <a class="thumb" href="/Store/Details/life-on-the-screen/_/R-9780684833484B"><img src="http://images.bookdepot.com/covers/large/isbn978068/9780684833484-l.jpg" alt="" class="cover" />
        <div class="price "><span>$</span>2.25
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="product-details">
    <dl>
        <dt><div class="nowrap"><span><a href="/Store/Details/life-on-the-screen/_/R-9780684833484B" title="Life On The Screen">Life On The Screen</a></span></div></dt>
        <dd class="type"><div class="nowrap"><span><a href="/Store/Browse/turkle-sherry/_/N-4294697489/Ne-4">Turkle, Sherry</a></span></div></dd>
        <dd class="type"><div class="nowrap"><a href="/Store/Browse/simon-and-schuster/_/N-4294151338/Ne-5">Simon and Schuster</a></div></dd>
        <dd class="type">(Paperback)</dd>
        <dd class="type">Computers &amp; Internet</dd>
        <dd class="type">ISBN: 9780684833484</dd>
        <dd>List $15.00 - Qty: 9</dd>
           </dl>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')

list_of_rows = []
for row in soup.findAll(True, {"class":["product-image", "product-details"]}):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll(['a', 'dd']):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.extend(list_of_cells)
print list_of_rows
```

output

```
[u'\n$2.25\n        \n', u'Life On The Screen', u'Turkle, Sherry', u'Turkle, Sherry', u'Simon and Schuster', u'Simon and Schuster', u'(Paperback)', u'Computers & Internet', u'ISBN: 9780684833484', u'List $15.00 - Qty: 9']
```

**Second case - you need to remove the new line character from html text**

```
list_of_rows = []
for row in soup.findAll(True, {"class":["product-image", "product-details"]}):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll(['a', 'dd']):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text.strip())
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
print list_of_rows
```

output

```
[[u'$2.25'], [u'Life On The Screen', u'Turkle, Sherry', u'Turkle, Sherry', u'Simon and Schuster', u'Simon and Schuster', u'(Paperback)', u'Computers & Internet', u'ISBN: 9780684833484', u'List $15.00 - Qty: 9']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I actually removed that line of text entirely from my code sample - it was just in there for debugging and I unintentionally left it in.  What I'm ultimately doing is outputting list_of_rows to a .csv file (I didn't bother to include that code, because the problem isn't in the writing out to the csv, it's in the structure of list_of_rows where every loop has multiple rows being written for output instead of a single.)  Hopefully I've clarified the problem - sorry for the accidental leaving in of the debug code.

Comment: Question is little confusing , still came up some solution , ,let me know of this works for you

Comment: That works perfectly!  Thanks for the help - I really appreciate it!

Comment: I did - unfortunately my rep isn't high enough (yet) for it to display (according to StackOverflow rules) even though it registers...

Comment: great ..happy that at least I was able to help you :)